# Are Voltage and current the same?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

If for example we have a wire bent in a circle, and current is the amount of charge that passes through cross-section in a second, could we raise current by raising the voltage, since the voltage is like water pressure by raising voltage we would make the charge move faster and thus more of them would pass through a cross-section of a conductor in second? Ofc the current would have to be small in order not to overheat the wire, but theoretically is possible, right?

Comment: @QMechanic: this post has already been answered

Comment: You might get other, better answers, if you hold off accepting any answers for 24 hours.

Comment: @QMechanic this post has already been answered
 Where?? can you give me link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is the rate at which charge flows through some chosen cross sectional surface in a wire. E.g if there is 1 coulomb of charge flowing through my chosen cross section in 1 second, then we say that the current is 1 ampere.

More generally

$I = \iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da} $

Voltage or potential difference  is defined as the amount of work that would be done against the electric field per unit charge, in moving  a unit charge from the negative to the positive terminal of a battery ( the reason its chosen from the negative to positive is so the voltage comes out positive)

$V = -\int_{-}^{+} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$

This Means if I have a 5 volt battery,  when electrons move from the negative to positive terminal,  each electron  would have a  potential energy  change of 5 * (-e) as potential energy is qV.

This also means that each electron would gain 5e J of energy from the electric field, as change in potential energy is the negative of change in kinetic energy.

Potential difference/voltage is a measure of how much energy that is transfered from the Field to the charge.

Obviously with resistance this energy isn't all being transfered as kinetic energy

Comment: Should i learn this from highschool book or college books? College right?

Comment: I have one more question; if I have 5V source and total resistance that consumes those 5V, how is circuit finished?
And thank you for answering the previous question.

Comment: What are called those equations that you have written? 
Do you know any books where I can learn all that? Some I can find on SCRIBD or another online library for free?

Comment: Found them at a local college for electrical engineers, thank you.

Comment: Okay, in ANY circuit. (In the absence of changing magnetic fields) the total voltage drop across all of your components, will be EXACTLY the voltage supplied by the bartery. This is because the line integral electric field is PATH INDEPENDANT. Meaning that any path from the negative terminal to the positive terminal will always have the exact same drop in potential along any path between those two points.

Comment: I think you are more wanting to describe ENERGY, for a component to run, it requires some power input ( energy per second) which is voltage * current. If the total ENERGY ( not voltage) of all of the components is equal to the total power supplied by the battery  then everything should work fine and everything will be powered

Comment: The formulas I described are the definition of potential difference, and the definition of current in the context of current density ( current/area). Prettu much every formula in Electromagnetism requires Multivariable Calculus. Before you even touch potential. I recommend going through "Khan academy Multivariable calculus", online. If you want to skip to the fundamental basics, look up "line integral" on their page. And then I would search up "work" and how it relates to an object change in kinetic energy

Comment: Have you seen any of these videos?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT1hNAIMk7U&t=3s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRMHNfug7Ec&t=26s

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Of5YnSVbZ80&t=85s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNmtFMuhDAY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwlEThO5VBw

What do you think about them?

Maglev trains work on same principle as the machine(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-rNILcfTKM&t=50s). I think it is true and real.

And  neodymium magnets are super strong

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Fishing-1000LBS-Neodymium-Pulling-Protective/dp/B08H5DB63G/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=fishing+magnet&qid=1644572209&sr=8-4

Neodymium magnets. 7.5 cm wide and 2.5 cm thick can lift 453 kg.

Which means that they have a lot of potential energy. The machine takes little energy to magnetize the iron core and produces more because of permanent magnet potential energy(453 kg potential energy) that is a lot. And they lose only 1% of their strenght every 100 years